# How to get child component's ref in Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question, if in the Class Component just attach the ref to the child component to get the whole ref, how can the hooks achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Same as in class components, you need to use forwardRef. check the pseudo code below

```
import {forwardRef} from 'react'
// wrap child component in forwardRef , with ref being a seperate argument to props
const ChildComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Child ref={ref} {...props} />
));
```

and in parent, just create the ref using useRef hook and pass to child

```
const ParentComponet =()=>{ 
  const ref = useRef(null)

  return (<ChildComponent ref={ref} {...props}/>)
}
```